# Rails .joins query over multiple associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have this query that works as expected:

`@dog.listings.joins(:address_country).merge(Country.where(permalink: 'uk'))`

This query gives me the Listings where the country matches 'uk' (Listing has_one :address_country, which is a country from the Country model)

But when I add another association to the chain in between cat and listing (litter), it doesn't work (a litter belongs to a listing, as well as to a cat):

`@dog.litters.joins(:listing) & Listing.joins(:address_country) & Country.where(permalink: 'uk')`

In this query I'd like it to fetch the Litters where the country (of the associated listing) matches. But it just returns an empty array. The first query works, and I guess I just need to bolt that on to `@cat.litters`?)

In Rails C, I'm getting this:

```
 d.litters.joins(:listing) & Listing.joins(:address_country).merge(Country.where(permalink: 'uk'))

  Litter Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "litters".* FROM "litters" INNER JOIN "listings" ON "listings"."id" = "litters"."listing_id" WHERE "litters"."litterable_id" = 11 AND "litters"."litterable_type" = 'Dog'
  Listing Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" INNER JOIN "countries" ON "countries"."id" = "listings"."address_country_id" WHERE "countries"."permalink" = 'uk'
=> []
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that's definitely wrong is to assume that `&` is the same as `merge`. It used to be but was removed in [fbd917](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fbd917f50a6046d02dd6a64ccfb1aed0cbce68d8) - now it's just [ruby's array intersection](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26) and that's not what you want.

I am not sure I follow the database schema from the brief description you gave but just rewriting it to merge is worth the shot:

```
@dog.litters.joins(:listing).merge(Listing.joins(:address_country)).merge(Country.where(permalink: 'uk'))
```

and again without actually running the code I would guess that this is equivalent:

```
@dog.litters.joins(listing: :address_country).where(countries: {permalink: "uk"})
```

Comment: Hi Jiří, thanks for the answer! Interestingly, the first example does not work (says 'Association named 'address_country' was not found') but the second one does :-) Any ideas why that is? I am glad you mentioned that about merge too, the Railscast I saw said they were the same (but it was in older cast). There dosen't seem to be many books or articles that cover these types of joins/queries, could you recommend any resources where I can learn more about them please? (I am an SQL beginner). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Not sure, I would have to investigate in the console... As for the resources, this one is a must read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks :) I ordered Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes as well.